# How to communicate back to a service from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

Hope someone can help me out here.  I will try to be concise!

I have a widget which starts a service. The service registers two broadcast receivers.  I would like to send back intents from the receivers to the service, so that the service can react.

I believe I read somewhere that 'starting' the service multiple times works, e.g. do the following in the receivers:

```
serviceIntent.setAction("me.SERVICE");
intent.putExtra("me.SERVICE", somedata);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

I remember reading (on some blog) that this won't start a new service, but will simply pass the intent to the already running service.  Is this correct?  Is it a bad way of doing it? Is there a better way?

Thanks very much!

Jack

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've used that approach in a pre-2.0 app.

Comment: It will work, but services changed.  See here: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Service.html ; Specifically, `onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)`

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using a singleton. I set a private variable (pointing to 'this') in the service's onCreate, and then used a static method called getInstance() which would return it. So later on, I simply call MyService.getInstance() to get hold of the service.

Comment: what happens if that variable is not initialized yet?